# Custom deserialization dart objects

Tags: flutter, dart

what classes I have are:

```
class Student {
  String name;
  String family;
}
```

```
class Info {
  int age;
  String phone;
}
```

but the server will give me a json like:

```
{
  "name": "mohammad",
  "family": "nasr",
  "age": 23,
  "phone": "+9345687544",
}
```

what I want is a class like :

```
@JsonSerializable()
class JsonResponse {
  Student student;
  Info info;
}
```

but the problem is that I will give jsonDecoding error because my `JsonResponse` class doesn't match the server response.

but I want my `JsonResponse` to be on that form,

Answer (score 1):

If you want your JsonResponse class to be in the form of

```
@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class JsonResponse {
  Student student;
  Info info;
}
```

and serialize the class, your response will be in the form of `{ student: {name: mohammad, family: nasr}, info: {age: 23, phone: +9345687544} },`, so you should change the JsonResponse class or use this

```
JsonResponse jsonResponse = JsonResponse.fromJson(
  Student.fromJson(jsonData), Info.fromJson(jsonData),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a deserialization method `fromJson` as shown below:

```
class Info {
  int age;
  String phone;

  Info({this.age, this.phone});

  factory Info.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if(json == null) return null;
    
    return Info(
      age: json['age'],
      phone: json['phone'],
    );
  }
}

class Student {
  String name;
  String family;

  Student({this.name, this.family});

  factory Student.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if(json == null) return null;
    
    return Student(
      name: json['name'],
      family: json['family'],
    );
  }
}

class JsonResponse {
  Student student;
  Info info;

  JsonResponse({this.student, this.info});

  factory JsonResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if(json == null) return null;
    
    Student student = Student.fromJson(json);
    Info info = Info.fromJson(json);

    return JsonResponse(student: student, info: info);
  }
}
```

The `fromJson` will take in `json` response from the server & convert it into your corresponding model object.

Comment: yes, but I want to implement it with ```JsonSerializable``` package which gives us code generation ability.